# Prevent "chcp" Changing Console Font

Tags: windows, command-line, fonts, batch-file, code-page

I am making a batch file that requires support for the different regions:

- `en-US`
- `zh-HK`

So, I used the `chcp` command to force the batch script to run in codepage 950(that's `zh-HK`).

However, I ran into an issue. When I run the batch file, the `chcp` command changes the font, and causes my batch script to show incorrect results.

How do I `chcp` to 950, without changing the font?

Comment: Are you shure your choosen font supports the glyphs/code points required for code page 950? And with what encoding did you save the batch?

Comment: @LotPings Courier New may not support the UTF-8 full block :(. And I save the script with UTF-8

Comment: May be time to switch to PowerShell supporting UTF16 (like windows does internal) but also no direct UTF8 support.

Comment: @LotPings Gaw :/ Gotta rewrite the entire script.. It's very long